# Error when using anomalize::time_decompose( ) - "length of assertion is not 1"

Tags: r, time-series

I have a tibble named `df` with two columns, `start_date` and `daily_visits`. Here's what it looks like when I call `str` on it:

```
str(df)
```

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1096 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ start_date  : Date, format: "2021-04-01" "2021-04-02" "2021-04-03" ...
 $ daily_visits: int  133 145 151 145 149 156 153 142 142 145 ...
```

I'm trying to pass this to the `time_decompose` function, similar to the example here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anomalize/vignettes/anomalize_quick_start_guide.html#minutes-to-anomalize

The code is simply:

```
df %>% time_decompose(daily_visits)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = start_date
Error: assert_that: length of assertion is not 1
```

I understand the first two messages, and they don't seem to be a problem; however, I have no clue whatsoever about what assertion is supposed to have length 1.

What should I do to make this function work?

Comment: It looks like you need to convert your data frame (`df`) to a tibbletime object. For some reason the conversion is failing.

Comment: Never mind, it's failing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug when the name of the date column is `start_date`. Try renaming the column to `date`. [I've opened up Issue 81 on GitHub.](https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime/issues/81)